# Problem with installing mathstone package

Tags: fonts, packages, texlive, texworks

I am trying to use the Stone Sans and Serif fonts in Texworks, which runs with Texlive. I downloaded the files for the font package to the relevant folders but was surprised by the following error message:

```
 Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
 (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk11.clo))
 (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
 (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))(./mathstone.sty)
 (./template.aux) (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathstone/ot1pst.fd)
 [1{c:/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
 (./template.aux)name = pstr8r, rootname = pstr8r, pointsize = 
 mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
 Cannot find font pstr8r in map file(s).

 kpathsea: Running mktexmf pstr8r.mf

 The command name is C:\texlive\2016\bin\win32\mktexmf
 Cannot find pstr8r.mf .
 I try ps2pk --> gsftopk --> ttf2pk --> hbf2gf.
 ps2pk cannot be used.
 I try gsftopk.
 gsftopk.exe pstr8r 657
 gsftopk cannot be used.
 Next I try ttf2pk.
 ttf2pk.exe -q pstr8r 657
 ttf2pk failed.
 Finally I try hbf2gf.
 hbf2gf.exe -q -p pstr8r 657
 All trials failed.
 )
 !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file pstr8r): Font pstr8r at 657 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Have you updated the file name database?

Comment: You mean from tex live manager?

Comment: I've done that already